# IF NOT EXIST not working in Windows Batch

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, ini

I am trying to insert an "if not exist" in a windows batch file where another similar IF with the same formatting IS working - can't tell why this one fails after researching and testing.

The second If not exist working as expected When the first is REMd out

Formatting is the same, %INIFile% is defined

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions Enabledelayedexpansion
set "TODAY=%Date:~4,2%-%Date:~7,2%-%Date:~12,2%"
set "NOW=%time:~0,2%.%time:~3,2%.%time:~6,2%"
set "TempFile=%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"
set "INIFile=Parameters_INI.ini"

if not exist ".\%INIFile%" (
    echo ERROR: List file "%INIFile%" not found.
    echo ERROR: List file "%INIFile%" not found.>>%LogFile%
    goto :EndBatch
)

:: Get Parameters
call :get-ini %INIFile% Parameters ListFile result
Set "ListFile=%result%"    
call :get-ini %INIFile% Output LogName result
Set "LogFile=%result%_%EntryName%_%TODAY%_T%NOW%_Log.txt"


Echo INI File Updater
Echo PC List: %ListFile%
Echo PC List: %ListFile%>>%LogFile%
    
if not exist ".\%ListFile%" (
    echo ERROR: List file "%ListFile%" not found.
    echo ERROR: List file "%ListFile%" not found.>>%LogFile%
    goto :EndBatch
)
goto :EndBatch

:get-ini <filename> <section> <key> <result>
  set %~4=
  set insection=
  for /f "usebackq eol=; tokens=*" %%a in ("%~1") do (
    set line=%%a
    if defined insection (
      for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%b in ("!line!") do (
        if /i "%%b"=="%3" (
          endlocal
          set %~4=%%c
          goto :eof
        )
      )
    )
    if "!line:~0,1!"=="[" (
      for /f "delims=[]" %%b in ("!line!") do (
        if /i "%%b"=="%2" (
          set insection=1
        ) else (
          endlocal
          if defined insection goto :eof
        )
      )
    )
  )

:EndBatch
endlocal
pause
```

Parameters_INI.ini

```
[Parameters]
ListFile=PCList.txt
Target=SMSStart.ini
TarDIR=Storeman
SectionName=[Maintenance]
EntryName=Reboot
NewValue=1

[Output]
LogName=INI_Update
```

PCList.txt

```
LAB-LANE005
LAB-LANE006
LAB-LANE001
LAB-LANE007
LAB-LANE008
```

Comment: Please read [mcve].

Comment: Read and reduced to it's reproducible fail state - REMing out the first IF NOT EXIST results in a working example.

Comment: As well as not having defined `%LogFile%` anywhere in your code prior to using it, you have also not defined your current working directory anywhere either. As we have no idea what your current directory is, we have no way of knowing, when you invoke the script, whether `Parameters_INI.ini` exists within it.

Comment: @Compo. The example runs out of any directory, all files in the same - and yes!, I see that now, the logfile is not defined prior to it's use, but in the section after... sometimes it's the easy things I miss. Thanks

Comment: If the script is always in the directory you're ini file is in, using the relative path `.\ ` will not necessarily be correct, because the batch file directory, will only really be the current directory, if the script is ran not elevated and from the GUI. You would be better advised to use full paths, or to specifically define your current directory from the outset. If the current directory is intended to always be that of the batch script itself, you should use `%~dp0` instead of `.\ `.

Comment: @Compo - Understood - and have used '%~dp0' extensively in the past.  Our environment dictates that something like this script could be run from a wide variety of locations, but always from the same DIR.  I ran into some issues with this script and was getting back to that.  THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    echo ERROR: List file "%ListFile%" not found.>>%LogFile%
```

You don't appear to have ever set `LogFile` to a value, so if it's not set, this line will fail when it's parsed as `>>` on it's own at the end of the line is invalid syntax, even if it's not run.

If you set `LogFile` before the batch file, or in the first lines of your batch file, the rest should work.